# Retrofit + GSON deserializer

Tags: android, dictionary, gson, retrofit, pojo

I have an object like this one:

```
"choice": {
    "000": {
             "id": "001",
             "label": "test",
             "status": "0"
     },
    "001": {
             "id": "001",
             "label": "test",
             "status": "0"
     },
    "002": {
             "id": "001",
             "label": "test",
             "status": "0"
     },
    "003": {
             "id": "001",
             "label": "test",
             "status": "0"
     },
    "004": {
             "id": "001",
             "label": "test",
             "status": "0"
     }
    },
```

How can I parse that object with Gson+Retrofit? Or generate a POJO? There is an easy way of doing this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea that all that you have in choice json object is Map:

```
public class RootObject{
    Map <String,ChoiceEntry> choice;
}

public class ChoiceEntry{
    String id;
    String label;
    int status;
}
```

Comment: Also you can edit your question and provide 'map' 'serialize' gson' keywords to make your question and my answer more reachable for other people with same problem.

Comment: [["test","test"],["test","test"],["test","test"],["test","test"],["test","test"],["test","test"],["test","test"]]

I have a POJO with a List of custom objects(with 2 strings). But its not working.

Comment: @Chronos because [] means that it is array (list). so now you have array of arrays. and you should have [{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}‌​,{...},{...}]. In this case it is list of objects. and inside {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2" }. It will be list of objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a POJO by pasting that JSON code into this link: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/.

You posted a snippet that isn't properly formatted.  I believe you'll have a multi-class POJO, and that is tricky to work with for certain uses such as listviews.

Let me know how it goes.  Retrofit's really nice to use, but extremely annoying to figure out!

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I recommend you http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, I think is better than the one you posted :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an [addon](https://github.com/HexarA/Json2Pojo) for intellij/android studio for easy POJO generation.

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the project.